# ASP.NET Image Upload path is correct but image is not displaying

Tags: asp.net

Actually i am trying to save the image in different project under the folder of images.Here i am getting the url is,

> D:\Projects\ECF\SVN\Codebase\ListView\ASP.NET\Code\AdvanceListView\AdvanceListView\Images\Empimage.jpg

the above url is correct, because that uploaded images is saved in the above path.But not displaying after uploading.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: Don't use file-based URLs in Web projects. Use either relative (`../images/image.jpg`) or absolute (`http://site/images/image.jpg`) instead